# Find the index of negative multiplying of two vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors and I want to find the index of multipling of these two vectors which gets negative and also `a[index]`is negative and `b[index]` is positive. How can I find this indexin R?

```
    a = c(1, -1, 2, 3, 4)
    b  =c(-1, 3, 5, 4, -5)
    c =  a*b
```

I have tried this but this is not my desire result:

```
    > which( c <= 0)
    [1] 1 2 5
```

the final result should be index = 1 and 5.

Comment: If the second condition is met (`a[index]` is negative then surely only `2` can be the desired result. Do you mean `a[index]` is positive and `b[index]` is negative?

Comment: Your example disagrees with your question statement. Please fix them.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your Question for 10 times, i think your regarded answer is 2 like Simon0101 says.

```
which( a < 0 & b >= 0 & c < 0)
```

Please review zour Question or the expected result.